# Change the time style of posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I used to use WordPress and the time at which the post was published was written in the form of (an hour ago). For example, now the time is mentioned (1 hour and 32 minutes ago). For example, I want to return it as it was previously so that I can mention the time of the post (an hour or two ago). )

Note: This time it will be in the list of posts in the WordPress

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.